# efibootmgr Ubuntu 0000 entry reapears after restart

Tags: boot, uefi, boot-loader

I deleted ubuntu partition from my dual boot. Now I am running only parrot security. Everytime I start my machine it falls into the GRUB error thingy because it automatically boots into Ubuntu, which is not there anymore. When I run efibootmgr from command line this appears

```
    $efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,3000,0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* Ubuntu
Boot0001* parrot
Boot0014* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)
Boot2002* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3004* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3005* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
```

When I delete the Ubuntu entry it deletes succesfully:

```
    #efibootmgr -b 0000 -B
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 3000,0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* parrot
Boot0014* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)
Boot2002* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3004* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3005* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
```

But then when I restart my machine it falls back into that GRUB error thingy and when I go to the boot options I see the Ubuntu entry still there. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: You may need to also change the boot order (with `efibootmgr -o 0001`) because after deleting the entry it shows 3000 as the boot priority and you want 0001 (Parrot) instead.

Comment: @MichaelBay Wow thanks that worked instantly. After deleting and changing boot order, the next restart everything stayed the same and no more GRUB error. Thanks

Comment: Great! Better post it as answer then. Later you can accept it so other users benefit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides deleting the "Ubuntu" entry, a boot order change is also necessary in this case:

```
#efibootmgr -o 0001
```

After deleting the entry it shows 3000 as the boot priority and you want 0001 (Parrot) instead.